# Check if a set of a field values is mapped against single value of another field in dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, filter

Consider the below dataframe with store and books available:

```
+-----------+------+-------+
| storename | book | price |
+-----------+------+-------+
| S1        | B11  | 10$   |  <<
| S2        | B11  | 11$   |
| S1        | B15  | 29$   |  <<
| S2        | B10  | 25$   |
| S2        | B16  | 30$   |
| S1        | B09  | 21$   |  <
| S3        | B15  | 22$   |
+-----------+------+-------+
```

Suppose we need to find the stores which have two books namely, `B11` and `B15`. Here, the answer is `S1` as it stores both books.

One way of doing it is to find intersection of the stores having book `B11` with the stores having book `B15` using below command:

```
val df_select = df.filter($"book" === "B11").select("storename")
.join(df.filter($"book" === "B15").select("storename"), Seq("storename"), "inner")
```

which contains the name of stores having both.

But instead I want a table

```
+-----------+------+-------+
| storename | book | price |
+-----------+------+-------+
| S1        | B11  | 10$   |  <<
| S1        | B15  | 29$   |  <<
| S1        | B09  | 21$   |  <
+-----------+------+-------+
```

which contains all records related to that *fulfilling* store. Note that `B09` is not left out. (Use case : the user can explore some *other* books as well in the *same* store)

We can do this by doing another intersection of above result with original dataframe:

```
df_select.join(df, Seq("storename"), "inner")
```

But, I see **scalability and readability issue** with `step 1` as I have to keep on joining one dataframe to another if the number of books are more than 2. Lots of pain to do and that's error-prone too. Is there a more elegant way to do the same? Something like:

```
val storewise = Window.partitionBy("storename")
df.filter($"book".contains{"B11", "B15"}.over(storewise))
```

Comment: S2 has both book, why it's filtered? if you use spark 2.4+, then try do array_except and filter by the size of the resulting array.

Comment: Ahh...I typed it by mistake. Corrected now..

Comment: can you use spark 2.4+?

Comment: Spark version is 2.4.0

Comment: Thanks @vdep and @jxc. Adding two concepts i.e. `collect_set` and `array_except` suggested by you guys, I am able to solve the issue. :)

Comment: A subquery might have solved your problem with ease, but why didn't you prefer that approach?

Comment: Please go ahead and put that as answer, I don't know exactly what you mean by subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple solution using [array_except](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@array_except(col1:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,col2:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function.

1. Add required set-of-field-values as an array in a new column, `req_books`
2. Add a column, `all_books`, storing all the books stored in a store using `Window`.
3. Using above two columns find if the store misses any required book, and filter them out if it misses anything.
4. Drop the excess columns created.

**Code**:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("req_books", array(lit("B11"), lit("B15")))
            .withColumn("all_books", collect_set('book).over(Window.partitionBy('storename)))

df1.withColumn("missing_books", array_except('req_books, 'all_books))
   .filter(size('missing_books) === 0)
   .drop('missing_book).drop('all_books).drop('req_books).show
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution @Saurav Sahu !!

Answer (score 0):

Using `Window` Functions to create array of all values and check if it contains all the necessary values.

```
val bookList = List("B11", "B15")  //list of books to search

def arrayContainsMultiple(bookList: Seq[String]) = udf((allBooks: WrappedArray[String]) => allBooks.intersect(bookList).sorted.equals(bookList.sorted))

val filteredDF = input
  .withColumn("allBooks", collect_set($"books").over(Window.partitionBy($"storename")))
  .filter(arrayContainsMultiple(bookList)($"allBooks"))
  .drop($"allBooks")
```

Comment: Works for 2 elements in list but **fails for more than 2 elements in list** with error as *org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'array_contains(...)' due to data type mismatch: Input to function array_contains should have been array followed by a value with same element type, but it's [array<bigint>, boolean].*

Comment: I checked it locally. Unfortunately doesn't work. Command is same as yours. It works perfectly for 2 elements list, but as soon as I add another element to the same list, it fails.

Comment: can you paste the code after your changes for more than 2 elements?

Comment: edited the answer. I tried to avoid `UDF`s earlier, but i found no inbuilt functions that suits your needs